# Vuetify Layout Issues: Toolbar Title and Panel Expansion

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify layout with 2 issues I cannot solve:

1. The toolbar title should be on the left and not floating away in the middle
2. The first panel should be expanded

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzxMmM?editors=1010

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    panels: [true, false]
  }
})
```

Comment: panel works good. thats.  expanding. no issues in chrome.  `<v-toolbar color="blue darken-3" app dark clipped-left
  >` moves the title text to left.

Comment: Can confirm the above, unless you want to have it expanded by default?

Comment: Also, these are two different issues/questions.

Comment: I know, my bad. I want the panel expanded by default which it's currently not - you have to click "Expand me!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVmqOB?editors=1010

Add `clipped-left` to v-toolbar

```
<v-toolbar color="blue darken-3" app dark   clipped-left>
```

and add `expand v-model="panels"` to `v-expansion-panel`

```
    <v-expansion-panel expand v-model="panels">
```